# ImageView in RelativeLayout clipped weirdly when layout_marginLeft or layout_marginTop set too high

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I am allowing the user to drag a RelativeLayout containing in ImageView (as well as some other stuff) around the screen. The layout wraps the ImageView within, and there is another Relative layout that places stuff on top of the ImageView. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        ... a couple text views that also fill parent

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am setting the src on the ImageView dynamically.

The user is able to drag the layout within another RelativeLayout the consumes the full screen. When the user moves it, I change the left and top margins. **I am seeing a strange problem where when the layout reaches the right or bottom edges of the screen, the Layout (and thus the ImageView that it is wrapping) is...**

- **Clipped on the left side as the right side of the layout goes off the right side of the screen**
- **Clipped on the top side as the bottom side of the layout goes off the bottom side of the screen.**

There is no problem at all when the layout is dragged to the left edge or top edge of the screen.

I have tried changing the ImageView's scaleType to all other values before I realized that the problem seems to be that the enclosing RelativeLayout is actually causing it (e.g. when I change the ImageView's scaleType to fitXY, the image gets squished to a tiny size as the layout is dragged off the edge of the screen).

I've also tried toggling every layout parameter I could find, including clipChildren, clipPadding, adjustViewBounds, margin, padding, etc., and nothings to really work. I am racking my brain on this simple problem that I thought should just work with the default parameters. To be clear, what I expect to happen is that as I drag the layout off the edge of the screen, the part that is off the screen is simply not seen any  more, and the stuff that is on screen stays as-is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Margin would normally allow part of your view to be rendered off screen. You'll have to max the margin so that margin + size < parent size (so it stays on screen). However you could try setting a negative right and bottom margin (doubt it'll work).